# issues with Android fastboot sensing devices

Tags: android, build, driver, fastboot

I've been having some issues getting fastboot to detect devices.  I've got my udev rule file set up as follows:

```
# adb protocol on passion (Nexus One)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e12", MODE="0666"
# fastboot protocol on passion (Nexus One)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTR{idProduct}=="0fff", MODE="0666"
# adb protocol on crespo/crespo4g (Nexus S)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e22", MODE="0666"
# fastboot protocol on crespo/crespo4g (Nexus S)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e20", MODE="0666"
# adb protocol on stingray/wingray (Xoom)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", ATTR{idProduct}=="70a9", MODE="0666"
# fastboot protocol on stingray/wingray (Xoom)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="708c", MODE="0666"
# adb protocol on maguro/toro (Galaxy Nexus)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0666"
# fastboot protocol on maguro/toro (Galaxy Nexus)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e30", MODE="0666"
# adb protocol on panda (PandaBoard)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0451", ATTR{idProduct}=="d101", MODE="0666"
# fastboot protocol on panda (PandaBoard)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0451", ATTR{idProduct}=="d022", MODE="0666"
# usbboot protocol on panda (PandaBoard)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0451", ATTR{idProduct}=="d010", MODE="0666"
```

and I've also tried the configuration specified on the [Android build page](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html).

I can see the device fine so long as it's not in fastboot mode.  I've started the server with the `adb start-server` command in both my normal user account as administrator, and am able to see the device in either instance.

I boot to the bootloader in order to try to use fastboot using the `adb reboot bootloader` command, and the phone responds appropriately.  However, after rebooting, I'm unable to access the phone using fastboot.  When I run the fastboot devices command as a normal user, I get the following:

```
$ fastboot devices
no permissions  fastboot
```

and when I run fastboot as root, I get the following about 3/4 times:

```
$ sudo ./fastboot devices
????????????    fastboot
```

Occasionally, the `sudo fastboot` command will work, and it will give me the correct MAC associated with the plugged in device.  Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Answer (score -1):

Add the OWNER="{your userid}" attribute to each of the udev rules.

[Ref](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/udev)

Comment: I also tried using the configuration copy-pasted from the android build page (as described in the question above) which has the group owner attribute - same effect as what you're describing.  A simple permissions issue would not explain why it happens sometimes, but not every time (as Linux permissions would not change in successive calls).

Comment: Well, I did  notice that the vendorid-productid combination as reported by lsusb (Assuming you're on a unix/linux host) did differ for the following scenarios (a) normal mode (b) debug mode (c) fastboot mode (d) ptp mode (e) mtp mode. I listed all of these combinations in my udev rules. Can you try the same and check? You might be experiencing the issue sometimes depending on how you're connected to your pc and which mode is currently in effect.